# Limiting NodeJS setImmediate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to have a loop in my NodeJS Environment that will execute 30 times a second (Based on a fixed variable). I've been told that `setInterval` and `setTimeout` isn't the way to go in terms of NodeJS as `process.nextTick` and `setImmediate` are available to comply with the I/O queue in NodeJS. I've tried using the following code (`setImmediate`):

```
var Physics = {
    lastTime: (new Date().getTime()),
    upsCounter: 0,
    ups: 0,

    init: function() {
        Physics.loop();
    },

    loop: function() {
        var currentTime = (new Date().getTime());
        Physics.upsCounter += 1;

        if((currentTime - Physics.lastTime) >= 1000) {
            Physics.ups = Physics.upsCounter;
            Physics.upsCounter = 0;
            Physics.lastTime = currentTime;

            console.log('UPS: ' + Physics.getUPS());
        }

        setImmediate(Physics.loop);
    },

    getUPS: function() {
        return this.ups;
    }

};
```

My problem is that Updates Per Second (UPS) is over 400,000, rather than the required 30, and I was wondering if there was any way to limit it down to this number, or an alternative loop structure. Thanks

Comment: I've been working with different multiplayer games, and using setInterval did not encountered any big issues at all.
Using setimmediate will call your function as soon as possible again once node.js is back to evented queue. So your part is to check if it is time to execute your loop logic, or if it is not yet - skip it. But it is wastage of CPU as so often check if time came - will load your Core up to 100%!
Effort required to align loop execution time to exact (1000 / 30)ms does not worth logical and resources effort. Use setTimeout, unless you found big issue with it yourself.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs Thank you for that comment, it's helped a lot. I've attempted to use `setInterval` and `setTimeout` with an interval of `(1000 / 30)`, but then the UPS output is 22 (Averaged out), and changing it to `(1000 / 60)` brings it up to an average of 39... Is there any reason it's doing this, or should I just ignore it and work with 22/39 UPS?

Comment: If single loop tick takes more than (1000 / 30)ms then there is no way that single process application will be able to keep time consistency - run this function 30 times a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been told that setInterval and setTimeout isn't the way to go in terms of NodeJS

Of course they are when you need a timeout or interval!

`setImmediate`/`nextTick` are *immediate*, which is not what you want. You cannot limit them, they are as fast as possible by design.

If `setInterval` is not accurate enough or drifting, then use a [self-adjusting timer](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/).

Comment: Thanks for this! I've read the Article and it makes a lot more sense now. Is there any chance you could write a quick example of how I could do this? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should go ahead and use the `setInterval` or `setTimeout` method, but make sure to unref them so they don't hold up the process that would otherwise exit, unless that timer is the main execution for the program.

see: [Node Timers API Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html)

`javascript
var t = setInterval(myMethod, 100);
t.unref(); //the timer t will not execute if the rest of the program is ready to exit.`